# I have problems copying char on the GPU with CUDA

Tags: cuda, char, memcpy

Host:

```
unsigned char exp[128];
unsigned char __e;

i = cudaMalloc( (void**)&__e, 128 * sizeof(unsigned char) );
if(i != cudaSuccess)
    printf("cudaMalloc __e FAIL! Code: %d\n", i);

BN_bn2bin128B(e, exp);  // copy data from e to exp, no problems since here

i = cudaMemcpy( &__e, &exp, 128 * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
if(i != cudaSuccess)
    printf("cudaMemcpy __e FAIL! Code: %d\n", i);
```

Output:

```
cudaMemcpy __e FAIL! Code: 11
```

Error 11 corresponds to:

```
cudaErrorInvalidValue = 11, ///< Invalid value
```

Why? Where is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared `__e` incorrectly. It must be a pointer. Try this:

```
unsigned char exp[128];
unsigned char * __e;

i = cudaMalloc( (void**)&__e, 128 * sizeof(unsigned char) );
if(i != cudaSuccess)
    printf("cudaMalloc __e FAIL! Code: %d\n", i);

// whatever goes here to set exp

i = cudaMemcpy( __e, &exp[0], 128 * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
if(i != cudaSuccess)
    printf("cudaMemcpy __e FAIL! Code: %d\n", i);
```